# I am stuck with C programming question based on arrays

Tags: c, arrays

The question is:
Given a 2-D array A of size M x N . Write a program in C to print A in spiral form starting from bottom right corner in anti-clockwise direction. There must be space after each element. Note the following

- 1<=M
- N<=20
- 0<=Aij<=1000

Example:

Input

```
1 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Output

```
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Input

```
3 3 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output

```
9 6 3 2 1 4 7 8 5
```

I have tried it....can anyone help me with this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int m,n;
    scanf("%d%d",&m,&n) ;
    int matrix[m][n] ;
    int last_row = (m-1) ;
    int last_column = (n-1) ; 
    int first_row = 0;
    int first_column = 0;
    int i=0,j=0,r=0,c=0;
    while(i<m)
    {      
        while(j<n)
        {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]) ;
            ++j;
        } j=0;
        ++i;
    } 
    while(first_column <=last_column && first_row <= last_row)
    {  for( r=last_row ; r>=first_row ; --r)
        {  c=last_column;

            printf("%d ",matrix[r][c]) ;

        } --last_column;

        for (c=last_column; c>=first_column ; --c)
        {
            r=first_row;
            printf("%d ",matrix[r][c]) ;

        } ++first_row ;
        for(r=first_row; r<=last_row; r++)
        {
            c=first_column;
            printf("%d ",matrix[r][c]) ;

        } ++first_column;
        for(c=first_column ; c<=last_column ; c++)
        {
            r=last_row;
            printf("%d ",matrix[r][c]) ;

        } --last_row;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The current output which I am getting is :

Input

```
8 1 
1
2
3 
4
5
6
7
8
```

Output

```
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Input

```
1 8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Output

```
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't forget to actually ask a question. What is the problem with the code you show?

Comment: I am not able to get desired output. I tried several times to figure out what`s wrong.

Comment: please explain what all did you try what is the problem exactly you are facing, I mean exactly what is the issue in your current output. Is  it an error, or something else.
These details will help people trying to help solve this problem

Comment: Yes please edit into your question what output you currently get.

Comment: You want to make sure you are writing to your matrix correctly while reading the input. In the 3x3 case you increase j with every input and trying to write into position matrix[1][4] which is out of its bounds. Add j=0; after every while(j<n) loop.

Comment: I have edited my code.It works in case of 3x3 but fails to give expected output in case of 8x1 and 1x8.

Comment: `while (i<n)` and `while (j<n)` - surely one of those `n`s should be an `m`?

Comment: I have edited my code.It fails to give expected output in case of 8x1 and 1x8.